# Best way to read a NetworkStream when using async Tcp

Tags: c#, asynchronous

This scenario assumes you are a client and have a single connection to the server.

If I start reading from a Tcp network stream using BeginRead, in the read callback I can just sit on the stream forever in a loop, letting it block and never calling BeginRead again.  This actually appears to work well but it seems wrong for some reason.  What are the pitfalls of doing this versus setting a read timeout, and calling BeginRead again on timeout?

Right now I see no advantages to using a read timeout.  My read is already happening in a separate thread so it's not blocking.  The blocking does not appear to be causing any cpu load.  My message rate is around 40 messages per second (incoming + outgoing).

I guess I could set a long read timeout just to catch possible connection issues.

Comment: How about writing some code and test it. That way you wouldn't have to make assumptions. I think Trial&Error is the best way to learn.

Comment: I thought that by mentioning that it seems to work well, the fact that I had code was implied. My question wasn't about whether it works, it was about whether there is something wrong with this approach that I am missing.